# Is USA safe for Indians currently

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, india, safety, event-based-effects

My very close friend and his wife, me and some friends are planning to travel to USA in couple of months as a vacation trip. But I keep on hearing news about Indians have been attacked/killed in USA from few weeks (specifically after new president elect), which is becoming very concern as to whether they should travel to US or some other country?

Currently is it safe for Indians to travel to USA? Do we need to take care of any things or precautions or keep in mind before we travel?

Sorry if my question is wrong but I need real answers for this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55744/discussion-on-question-by-veera-kannadiga-is-usa-safe-for-indians-currently).

Answer (score 6):

Veera, as in any question about safety, it is subject to circumstances.  The United States is very, very big, and even in the smallest country anything can happen.

Every complete answer here should include that last caveat.

The population for people of South Asian descent is [almost 4 million people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Americans).  The recent targets are reminiscent of other hate crimes, but are just that: atrocious hate crimes.

When traveling to any country, you should always stay in safe areas, surrounded by people, treating locals with respect, asking questions when you don't know protocol.

As a litmus test, you might flip the question: would a visibly identifable Western person be unsafe in India?  Considering anti-Western terrorist groups exist there; foreign terrorist organizations, which are active in India, including Islamist extremist groups such as Harkat-ul-Jihad-i-Islami, Harakat ul-Mujahidin, Indian Mujahideen, Jaish-e-Mohammed, and Lashkar-e Tayyiba.  Is a Westerner unsafe in India because of this?

Of course not - I am visibly Western and have loved my travels throughout India for years and all of the people I've met.  The actions of some are not the actions of a country; and certainly not going to happen in populated tourist areas.

Always practice good personal security. Be aware of your surroundings (including customs and etiquette) and keep a low profile.  Pickpocketing can be an issue in large cities (well, anywhere, but you know what I mean).  Avoid dimly lit areas at night in dodgy neighborhoods, etc.

Let travel.se know your experience when you've visited, in chat!  And, namaste!

EDIT: As stated in the comments to your question, do NOT hesitate to ask for help if you feel unsafe in any way.  911 is the calling code for emergency, and it will also give you the non-emergency number for the region you are in, which is a good number to keep in your phone.

Comment: The safety of westerners in India is irrelevant to a question about the exact opposite. So what if India might look dangerous to westerners but is actually fine? The question is about whether the USA is safe for Indians.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - this is my point; speculation based on news and impressions is the same.  Perhaps the OP can assess that Travel is travel, and there's currently no travel warnings (that I'm aware of) to travel between either countries from either side.  Maybe I should have been more explicit.  It was used as a comparison.

Comment: Knowing that the impression one might get about situation X from the media is false doesn't tell you whether the impression you might get about situation Y from the media is false. For example, this argument about the USA applies just as well to Syria: from the media, I get the impression that Syria is dangerous for people like me but, pfft, it's just the media, I should ignore it. You can only come to conclusions about whether it's safe to visit the USA by using evidence about the USA. Evidence about India isn't relevant.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - I'm in complete agreement with you.  I am stating that news articles do not a country's tourism make.